# List of all errors in exim

Tags: logging, linux-networking, exim

Is there any link/documentation which we can refer for any errors related to exim. Giving brief info about the kind of error or reason for the error.

Thanks
Alok

Answer (score 0):

http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch49.html provides a list of errors and explanations.